# How to compare an array variable and Normal variable using if condition in PHP

Tags: php

I want to compare an array variable and Normal variable using if condition in PHP..
I have an Array VAriable as .$AllowedEnquiryType[$i] and a variabe as $TIntType how to check these to are equal.

My coding is

```
for($i=1;$i<=$length;$i++)
    {
        if($AllowedEnquiryType[$i]==$TIntType) 
        {   
             return true;
        }
        else
        {

            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Dont see any problem too. Maybe, that it just compares only the first element? Thats because you `return` from the method/function/file right at the first iteration. Also usually arrays begin with `0` (not `1`) and the last element is `$length -1` and not `$length`.

Comment: How an array could be equal to a scalar ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to check if `$AllowedEnquiryType[$i]` and `$TIntType` are equal, you already wrote what to do :

```
if ($AllowedEnquiryType[$i] == $TIntType) {
    // those are equal
}
```

Else, if you want to check if all items of `$AllowedEnquiryType` are equal to `$TIntType`, you could do something like this :

```
$allEqual = true;
for($i=1;$i<=$length;$i++) {
    if ($AllowedEnquiryType[$i] != $TIntType) {
        $allEqual = false;
        break;  // no need to check the other items
    }
}

if ($allEqual) {
    // all items in $AllowedEnquiryType are equal to $TIntType
}
```

Comment: Perhaps add a little `break;` inside the `if`-statement... Just to make sure we bail out of the loop if further processing is not required any more.

Answer (score 0):

use `in_array`

[link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `if($AllowedEnquiryType[$i]==$TIntType)`. What exactly are you asking for?